# Create hyperref form fields with macro

Tags: macros, hyperref, renewcommand

I would like to create a macro that will help me configure hyperref form fields.

Can someone tell me why my minimal example does not work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{textfeldcounter}
%\newcommand{\Macroname}[Anzahl der Übergabeparameter]{\Formatierungsbefehl{#Nummer_Übergabeparameter}}
\newcommand{\tf}[4]{
\TextField[name=name\value{textfeldcounter},width=#1,height=#2,multiline=#3,bordercolor=black, charsize=#4]{}
\stepcounter{textfeldcounter}
}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{textfeldcounter}{1}
\tf[1cm][1em][true][9pt]\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to use curly braces for the arguments: `\tf{1cm}{1em}{true}{9pt}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{textfeldcounter}
%\newcommand{\Macroname}[Anzahl der Übergabeparameter]{\Formatierungsbefehl{#Nummer_Übergabeparameter}}
\newcommand{\tf}[4]{
\TextField[name=name\the\value{textfeldcounter},width=#1,height=#2,multiline=#3,bordercolor=black, charsize=#4]{}
\stepcounter{textfeldcounter}
}
\begin{document}
\Form
\setcounter{textfeldcounter}{1}
\tf{1cm}{1em}{true}{9pt}
\end{document}
```